# How to achieve occlusion culing in threejs？

Tags: javascript, three.js, occlusion-culling

hello，Now I have a research direction, the development of visual large-scale 3D building on the web, but the number is too large and found that threejs has no good way to achieve occlusion culing, may I ask what is a good way to achieve this?Frustum Culling has been achieved。I am a student from China, the translation is from google, sorry。

Comment: Several spatial partitioning algorithms are available which allow conservative culling, such as octrees. It is even possible (though very complex) to compute the exact set of polygons visible from a volume. Some engines use portals between rooms and compute how many portals are visible, requiring rendering of the connected room's polygons.

Comment: Invisible has been removed, and now need to be considered in the field of vision is blocked by other objects how to remove

Comment: Two possible solutions (out of many more, I guess) would be to use LOD or clipping. If your goal is to improve performance in a crammed scene then I recommend you look into these

Comment: lod is considering, and now a little better idea is to follow the occlusion culing unity unity to do, but do not know unity occlusion culing ideas